# Cannot use Zend_Debug::dump in ZF2..how do I?

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm using the skeleton application for ZF2.0.0Beta3.

So, normally I would just use Zend_Debug::dump($someVar); however, in ZF2 it doesn't include the zend classes it seems.

```
The error is: Fatal Error: Class 'Zend_Debug' not found..
```

This is probably a really basic question, but what's the best way to include that class? Do I have to put `require_once('path/to/Debug.php');`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It still exists in ZF2, but since ZF2 started using PHP [namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php), you would now have to call it using the `Zend` namespace:

`\Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($var);`

or add a [use](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) statement at the beginning of the file and call it like this:

```
use Zend\Debug\Debug;

Debug::dump($var);
```

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot! 

Zend\Debug::dump('sfasdf');

I know it was a dumb question, but hopefully someone else benefits from it also. Thanks stackoverflow, for lowering the required IQ for programming.

Comment: Well I've been using PHP a long time and its an interesting change, I'm still adjusting to it myself :)  It's a far cry from the PHP 3 days.

Comment: sure using the `use` keyword is the way to go but in a view who wants to quickly write \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump(---); for a quick dump of a variable??? I highly think this is a waste of time!

Answer (score 5):

In my case this was the correct namespace-path :

```
\Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($form);
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, you can get it like this:

```
use Zend\Debug\Debug;

// ...

Debug::dump($someVar);
```

Seems like a lot of work just to dump a variable, though.  I'm pretty sure in most case I'll just end up using `\Zend\Debug\Debug::dump()` more often.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like that:

```
\Zend\Debug::dump('asd')
```